# How can I tell ReSharper to stop creating readonly fields?

Tags: resharper, resharper-5.0

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565768/why-does-resharper-suggest-readonly-fields) is similar, but my question seems to get asked in an unanswered comment.

I create a C# class.  I use <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>insert</kbd> to add a constructor.  I add an argument to the constructor, and then I use <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd> to create and initialize a field from that argument, like so:

[image]

The problem is that my field gets created as a `readonly` field, and in many cases I do not want to create a readonly field.

```
readonly int my_int;
```

How can I tell ReSharper not to add make my field readonly?  I've tried to do a pretty thorough search in the ReSharper options, but apparently I'm missing something!

Comment: Why don't you want to name fields readonly?

Comment: Because ultimately this field is not intended to be readonly.  In some cases, sure, I want readonly.  But at this point I have just introduced the field and would prefer that it's not created as readonly.

Comment: I agree, I hate that in resharper! This auto readonly just pollute my code most of the time.

Answer (score 4):

I too cannot find any option to change the creation default; **however**, if you allow R# to create this field as it likes (ie `readonly`), and later type this:

```
public void Bar(int baz)
{
    my_int = baz;
}
```

then the assignment to `my_int` will get a red squiggly underline, since it is illegal, and the offered quick fix (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) at that location will be `Make field 'my_int' non-readonly`.

So in the spirit of 'code first', you might want to just let R# do its thing, and also use it to change it as and when you actually need it changed (which might of course turn out to be never...)

Answer (score 2):

The field creation is hardcoded to be readonly on creation. The idea is that you're creating a field, so it doesn't have any usages to default to the most restrictive, if you try to write to it elsewhere, you can alt+enter at that point and remove the readonly status. If the field already exists, ReSharper will try and initialise the existing field from the parameter.

If you want to, you can write a plugin to generate the field as non-readonly. You should look at the `IntroduceFieldFix` class in dotPeek. It's got several constructors, which binds the quick fix to the warning squigglies, and it will introduce a field using the default pattern for the current language (which is hardcoded to "`private readonly $0 $1;`")

You can create a class that also derives from `InitializeFieldFix`, and includes a constructor that takes `UnusedParameterWarningBase` as a parameter. You can then follow the same implementation as `IntroduceFieldFix`, but provide a different pattern for the field creation, checking for the current language first.

Comment: that was what i also concluded. writing an addin was not a path i wanted to go down

Comment: there should really be an option to turn this off

Answer (score 2):

Another option may be to use 'Introduce Field' refactoring instead. The best way to call it is to use 'Refactor This' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) on a parameter declaration and choose 'Introduce Field' from the reduced number of refactoring options. By default it will generate writable field but there is also an option to change modifiers.